# How to run a command/script from main tab in PyCharm to get return in lower tab (terminal or Python console tab)?

Tags: python, pycharm

How to run a command/script from main tab in PyCharm to get return in lower tab (terminal or Python console tab)?

I'm getting following error.

I'm working with ODrive PCB (driver)
https://odriverobotics.com/
https://docs.odriverobotics.com/

image is a screenshot from PyCharm:
[image: image is a screenshot from PyCharm]

Comment: you can do something like this `def func:  return print(value)` instead of returning value, you can directly print it to console when you run the code,if this is not your case,  Can you please elaborate your question

Comment: I need to run a whole list of commands in one script (to control motor via PCB called ODrive) and I'm looking for a way how to do it in any IDE that I do not have to keep copying and pasting those commands into terminal. I just want to run it as a complete script but I'm getting this error in PyCharm.